# How to change chapter font color and chapter number color

Tags: color, environments, thesis

How can I change the chapter number color and chapter name color?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont\thechapter}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\LARGE#1}\        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \mbox{}}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\LARGE#1}\        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A Long Title for an Unnumbered Test Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace the 3rd argument of `\titleformat` (`{\normalfont\sffamily}`) with`{\normalfont\sffamily\color{my colour}}` if the chapter label and the chapter title must have the same colour.

Comment: @And which  command change only the chapter number or title?.

Comment: For the chapter number, `\parbox[b]{\color{label colour}\chapnumb}`, for the title, `{\color{title colour\LARGE#1}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \fontsize{120}{110}\selectfont\textcolor{red}{\thechapter}}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\textcolor{blue}{\LARGE#1}}\        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
   \mbox{}}%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \hfill{\textcolor{blue}{\LARGE#1}}\        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{A Long Title for an Unnumbered Test Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```